# Getting undefined is not an object in React native when rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to `React` and `React native` and am trying to `retrieve data from an API` and then render it but I seem to be running into problems.

I can grab the data from the `API` alright, but when I try and `render` it I'm getting all sorts of errors.

Essentially all I'm trying to do is render the photos that are returned from the API. Should be simple right? Would appreciate anyone who can point me in the right track.

I'm getting errors like:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.photos') in RenderPhotos_render

I may have jumped into `React Native` too early...So excuse my lack of knowledge!

```
var AwesomeProject = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        isLoading: true,
        photos: this.props.photos
      };
    },
    componentWillMount: function(){
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/photos/", {
          method: "GET", 
          headers: {
            "x-access-token":"xxxxx",
            "x-key":"xxxx"
          },
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            AlertIOS.alert(
                "GET Response",
                "Search Query -> " + JSON.stringify(responseData)
            )
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false
            });
            this.setState({
              photos: JSON.stringify(responseData)
            });
        })
        .done();
    },
    render: function() {
        if(this.state.isLoading){
          return <View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>
       }
        return (
            <RenderPhotos photos={this.props.photos}/>
        );
    },

});

var RenderPhotos = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        photos: this.props.photos
      };
  },
  render: function(){
    var photos = Photos;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> {this.props.photos[0]} </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, the prop you pass to `RenderPhotos` is `this.props.photos`, which is undefined in `AwesomeProject`. Looking in the `render()` function of `RenderPhotos`, you try to access the element at index 0 of `this.props.photos`, which is undefined. That's probably what's causing your error. I suspect you meant to set the photos prop equal to `this.state.photos` in the `render()` function of the `AwesomeProject` component.

Second, inside `componentWillMount()` of the `AwesomeProject` component, you make two state changes after you get photos from the API:

```
this.setState({
  isLoading: false
});

this.setState({
  photos: JSON.stringify(responseData)
});
```

It's possible, but not guaranteed, that React might batch those two `setState()` calls, so both state properties would be set at the same time and the `render()` method would be called only once. However, if these `setState()` functions are executed synchronously, the `render()` function will be called while `this.state.loading === false` and `this.state.photos === undefined`. The `RenderPhotos` component will mount and receive the prop `photos={this.state.photos}` (after making the change I described above). Unfortunately, because `this.state.photos` is undefined, you will encounter the same problem as above when you try to access `this.props.photos[0]` inside the `render()` function of `RenderPhotos`. Here's my suggestion to fix your problem:

```
var AwesomeProject = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        isLoading: true,
        photos: this.props.photos
      };
    },
    componentWillMount: function(){
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/photos/", {
          method: "GET", 
          headers: {
            "x-access-token":"xxxxx",
            "x-key":"xxxx"
          },
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            AlertIOS.alert(
                "GET Response",
                "Search Query -> " + JSON.stringify(responseData)
            )
            // Set both state properties at the same time to avoid passing an undefined value as a prop to RenderPhotos
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              photos: JSON.stringify(responseData)
            });
        })
        .done();
    },
    render: function() {
        if(this.state.isLoading){
          return <View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>
       }
       // RenderPhotos should receive this.state.photos as a prop, not this.props.photos
        return (
            <RenderPhotos photos={this.state.photos}/>
        );
    },

});

var RenderPhotos = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        photos: this.props.photos
      };
  },
  render: function(){
    var photos = Photos;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> {this.props.photos[0]} </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: A small modification is you could drop the state from RenderPhotos since you are no longer using it

Comment: Also the var photos = Photos is pointless in the render function. And finally this.props.photos start out as undefined (maybe, the state is set by a property that isn't shown) which would end in a undefined error since you go straight to trying to display index 0 of the array.

Answer (score 28):

> **for those who dont find solution to their problems in answers above:-**

This solved my problem:
I changed code from

```
import {React} from 'react';
```

to

```
import React from 'react';
```

What happened is, since `React` is exported by default from the module so I cannot wrap it with curly-braces.

Comment: Thank you sir! I was stuck for 1 hour on this :)